# Xamarin iOS how to make different xib for iPad and iPhone with same ViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to make one view which will contain different UI for iPad and iPhone but 
 both will use the same ViewController.

Will it be possible?

If Yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create another xib named `YourVCName~ipad`.
   [image]
2. Double click the xib,select file's owner class as your viewcontroller.

   [image]
3. Override `LoadView` method in your viewcontroller.

   ```
   public override void LoadView()
   {
       base.LoadView();
       if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Model == "iPad")
       {
           string xibName = "ViewController1~ipad";
           UIView v = UINib.FromName(xibName, null).Instantiate(null, null)[0] as UIView;
           View.Add(v);
       }
   }
   ```

Then you see two different xib can be displayed on different platforms.